# check site status from csv powershell

Tags: powershell, iis-7, import-csv

Am trying to read a status of website to make sure sites is running. sites is store as csv file in d drive. here is what my code looks like

```
#
$file = "C:\Config\script.csv" 

$csv = Import-Csv $file -Header "url" |select -expand url |%{ [System.Net.Webrequest]::Create("$_")}

foreach ($row in $csv) {



    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$_")

    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

    $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

  If($HTTP_Status -eq 200){


    Write-Host "Site is OK"


  }

  Else{

  Write-Host "The Site is down, please check!"
  }

  $HTTP_Response.Close()

}
```

Comment: What specific part are you having problems with?

Comment: this part [System.Net.Webrequest]::Create("$_")} am getting error Exception calling "Create" with "1" argument(s):

Comment: The second $_ is empty your not in a pipe where you can use $_

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-Csv .\test.csv  -Header "url" |  foreach {
    $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create("$($_.url)")
    $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

    If([int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode -eq 200){
         Write-Host "Site is OK"
    }
    Else{
         Write-Host "The Site is down, please check!"
    }
    $HTTP_Response.dispose()
}
```